# Strange message at the top of the screen: external JavaScript ... is blocked or failed to load

Tags: support, javascript

When viewing [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123225/examples-of-estimation-from-a-function), I receive the following message with big white letters on red background:

> Cross Validated requires external JavaScript from another domain,
>   which is blocked or failed to load.

What does this mean?